# Qt пример по работе с modbus

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Добрый день!

Разбираюсь в примере QT по работе с modbus, не могу понять вот эту строчку:

```
auto valueChanged = static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)> (&QSpinBox::valueChanged);
```

Идет приведение типов и обращение к члену класса, но какому именно? и что означает знак > ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса QSpinBox есть два сигнала с одинаковым именем, но разной сигнатурой:

```
void    valueChanged(int i)
void    valueChanged(const QString &text)
```

По-этому при записи, компилятор просто не поймет, указатель на какую из перегруженных функции нужно использовать:

```
auto valueChanged = &QSpinBox::valueChanged;
```

Для того чтоб "подсказать" компилятору и используется это монструозное приведение типа функции

```
 static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)> (указатель на функцию);
```

В Qt есть возможность использовать более короткую конструкцию для этого:

```
auto valueChanged = QOverload<int>::of(&QSpinBox::valueChanged);
```

Символ > является частью указания типа у static_cast

```
static_cast<тип_функции>(указатель_на_функцию);
```

Comment: Спасибо! На счет знака > уже потом понял, что это же кусок от статик каста!